# How to simulate a value in R from a lower and upper boundary assuming that these are all uniformly distributed?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 1,100 x 3
   income       minimum       maximum
    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     NA            NA            NA
 2      0             0            25
 3      0             0            25
 4     NA            NA            NA
 5      4           100           200
```

I want to simulate a value from the minimum and maximum value under the assumptions that these follow a uniform distribution.

Any idea how to do this?
The simulated values should appear on the right side under the variable income.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
df$salary <- runif(nrow(df)) * (df$upperboundary - df$lowerboundary) + df$lowerboundary
```

`runif` default interval is 0-1. With this operation you transform it to your boundaries. It is the fastest solution.

With `dplyr` if your code is tidyverse oriented:

```
df %>% mutate(salary = runif(n()) * (upperboundary - lowerboundary) + lowerboundary)
```

However, it is also possible to define the boundaries directly:

```
df$salary <- runif(nrow(df), df$lowerboundary, df$upperboundary)
```

If you had no NAs, this one would be the optimal and fastest solution.
It is anyway the most readable. [Thanks to @user20650 for your help!]

---

Additional details.

How does this work?

```
runif(nrow(df)) * (df$upperboundary - df$lowerboundary) + df$lowerboundary
```

Let's look at 1 and let's define manually a max and a min.

By default `runif(1)` is equal to:

```
runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
```

Therefore, it return a random number between 0 and 1 according to a uniform distribution.

To return a random number between two different limits, say for instance `min = 10` and `max = 20`, you can do it this way:

```
runif(1, min = 10, max = 20)
```

or

```
min <- 10
max <- 20
runif(1, min = 0, max = 1) * (max - min) + min
```

if the output of runif is 0:

```
0 * (20 - 10) + 10
==> 10
```

if the output of runif is 1:

```
1 * (20 - 10) + 10
==> 20 - 10 + 10
==> 20
```

---

Here also an alternative with `dplyr` to the solution with `apply`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(salary = runif(1, lowerboundary, upperboundary)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

---

Here's a speed comparison. The "maths" one is the fastest:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply  =  apply(df[-1],1, function(x) runif(1, x[1], x[2])),
  maths  =  runif(nrow(df)) * (df$upperboundary - df$lowerboundary) + df$lowerboundary,
  maths2 =  runif(nrow(df), df$lowerboundary, df$upperboundary),
  dplyr  =  df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(runif = runif(1, lowerboundary, upperboundary)) %>% ungroup()
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>   apply  907.1  955.90 1175.188 1023.70 1280.90 4455.0   100
#>   maths   16.8   26.05   32.651   31.25   38.65   75.0   100
#>  maths2  117.8  128.00  156.533  136.60  175.15  336.7   100
#>   dplyr 1424.2 1496.60 1821.068 1661.15 1989.20 3952.7   100
```

Comment: I think its enough to do `with(df, runif(nrow(df), lowerboundary, upperboundary))`

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. you're right! I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit; Id imagine that if the size of data increased then maths and math2 would be similar

Comment: you're correct. cnsidering its data size, math2 it's a better choice. More readable also...

Comment: apparently the presence of NAs slows down math2

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, salary, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 25364

Comment: Please check your dataframe is called df. Otherwise replace df in the solution with the actual name of your dataframe

Comment: It worked. But could you explain step by step the following code. I'm new to R.

Comment: df$salary <- runif(nrow(df)) * (df$upperboundary - df$lowerboundary) + df$lowerboundary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222875/discussion-between-vahis100-and-edo).

Comment: I've added some extra details

Comment: There is a problem: When I count the missings of the variable income and salary, they should be equal because if the income is not observed then salary should also be returned NA.                                                                                         count(dfnew, '+(is.na(income))')
  X..is.na.income.. freq
1                 0  755
2                 1  737
> count(dfnew, '+(is.na(salary))')
  X..is.na.salary.. freq
1                 0  748
2                 1  744

Comment: Maybe you have some extra NAs in the upper and lower bounds. Isolate the rows where income is not missing and salary is. And check what happens there. `df %>% filter(!is.na(income), is.na(salary))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach with `apply()`. You can use `runif()` to generate the value using `lowerboundary` and `upperboundary` variables at row level. For those rows with `NA` you will get `NaN`. Here the code:

```
#Code
df$Salary <- apply(df[,-1],1,function(x) {y <- runif(1,x[1],x[2]); y})
```

Output:

```
   income lowerboundary upperboundary     Salary
1      NA            NA            NA        NaN
2       0             0            50   26.86049
3       0             0            50   36.44212
4      NA            NA            NA        NaN
5       4           425           600  459.25802
6      NA            NA            NA        NaN
7      NA            NA            NA        NaN
8       4           425           600  535.39891
9      NA            NA            NA        NaN
10     12          2400          3000 2754.34136
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(income = c(NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
12L), lowerboundary = c(NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 425L, NA, NA, 425L, NA, 
2400L), upperboundary = c(NA, 50L, 50L, NA, 600L, NA, NA, 600L, 
NA, 3000L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(salary = map2_dbl(lowerboundary, upperboundary, ~ runif(1, .x, .y)))
```

-output

```
#   income lowerboundary upperboundary      salary
#1      NA            NA            NA         NaN
#2       0             0            50   33.771312
#3       0             0            50    3.577857
#4      NA            NA            NA         NaN
#5       4           425           600  514.912989
#6      NA            NA            NA         NaN
#7      NA            NA            NA         NaN
#8       4           425           600  516.179313
#9      NA            NA            NA         NaN
#10     12          2400          3000 2815.442543
```